# HTML/CSS Create three columns with border shaded

Tags: html, css

[image: with borders shaded in red]

Can someone please help? thank you!

Thank you everyone.
Here's what I got so far.  I am trying to put these in separate box with round border. Different background color for title (soccer, baseball, baseketball) I want to make tabs for the titles.

```
<div class="jive-html-text-widget">
   <style type="text/css">
      .third {float:left; width:32%; margin-left:1%;}
      .third:first-child {margin-left:0;}
      .third h2 {font-family: "consolas"; color:#762432; margin-bottom:12px;}
      .third p {font-family: "consolas"; color:#2B547E; margin-bottom:12px;}
      .third ul {margin:0 0 22px 30px;}
      .third ul li {margin-bottom:8px;}
      .third li {font-family: "consolas"; color:#2B547E}
   </style>
   <div class="jive-html-text-widget">
      <div class="jive-html-text-widget">
         <hr/>
         <div class="third">
            <h2>Baseball</h2>
            <ul class="noindent">
               <li>a ball game played between two teams of nine on a field with a diamond-shaped circuit of four bases. It is played chiefly in the US, Canada, Latin America, and East Asia.</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="third">
            <h2>Soccer</h2>
            <ul class="noindent">
               <li>a game played by two teams of eleven players with a round ball that may not be touched with the hands or arms during play except by the goalkeepers. The object of the game is to score goals by kicking or heading the ball into the opponents' goal.</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="third">
            <h2>Basketball</h2>
            <ul class="noindent">
               <li>Originally invented in the movie BASEketball, starring South Park creators Trey Parker and Matt Stone, BASEketball has evolved from a fictional game to a popular real-life sport![1] It might have started as a joke, but BASEketball has rules just like the sports it started from.</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: we can, but what you coded so far?

Comment: We'll need some code to help you out at all. Please take some time to visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [how to ask a great question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Maybe you want to use the column property and break-inside  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/break-inside/  but checkout the compatibility  http://caniuse.com/#search=column

Answer (score 0):

Hi check this https://plnkr.co/edit/kAEDONthQYYgB54Sc7Tz?p=preview for refrence

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">

   <div class="column-left">Column left The border-left shorthand property sets all the left border properties in one declaration.The properties that can be set, are (in order): border-left-width, border-left-style, and border-left-color.</div>
   <div class="column-center">Column centerThe border-left shorthand property sets all the left border properties in one declaration.The properties that can be set, are (in order): border-left-width, border-left-style, and border-left-color.</div>
   <div class="column-right">Column right</div>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

and CSS

```
.container {
    width: 100%
}
.container div {
    height: 300px;
}
.column-left {
    left: 0;
    width: 30%;
    background: #00F;
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.column-center {
    width: 30%;
    background: #933;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.column-right {
    width: 30%;
    right: 0;
    background: #999;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```